# using Methods provided by declared field Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

i was looking through the Class and found that you can get the declared fields and methods

my question is can i get the methods provided by declared fields

like the fields that are instances of classes that need args in their constructor

i mean something like `class#getDeclaredField()#getType()#getDeclaredMethods()`?

i know that wont work but can such a thing work without returning null or getting a NPE?

i mean would it use the decalred field to get the methods
like how i do with a code `class.field.doSomething();`

if field is a class which need args in it's constructor like SomeClass(String para, int num, ...)

or will it just set it to a new one or null

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking if it's possible to get `Constructor` instances?

Comment: I don't understand either. Please explain the problem a little better.

Comment: I think you need to read a small tutorial about reflections and then you can test whatever you like. The way you instantiate objects or call their methods using reflection is totally different with normal way.

Answer (score 1):

Field.getType() returns Class. You can get its methods (and fields) the same way you get them from the target class.

Comment: thanks, and yeah i know but i was getting NPE or some other error before, but now i rewote it same thing excatly and seem to be working